# How do I solve a "Working outside of request context" and Expected request method to be 'POST', found 'GET' instead in Plotly/Dash get_user_data()?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am working on setting up a Plotly/Dash demo, but I've run into difficulty with using the sf_auth.get_user_data() function. Specifically it returns two different errors.

`"Working outside of request context"`

and

`Expected request method to be 'POST', found 'GET' instead`

Here is the source code I've got running

```
[app.py]

import dash
from dash_embedded import SalesforceAuth
import os

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions = True)

sf_consumer_secret = os.getenv("SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_SECRET", "")
session_secret_key = os.getenv("SESSION_SECRET_KEY", "secret")  

sf=False

if sf==True:
    sf_auth = None
    print('SF is NONE')
else:
    print('SF is SOMETHING')
    sf_auth = SalesforceAuth(app, sf_consumer_secret, session_secret_key)
    if sf_auth is None:
        print("couldn't authorize w/ salesforce")
    print("!!!!! after auth !!!!!!")
    print(sf_auth)
    print("******** after printing sf_auth object *******")
    print(sf_auth.get_user_data)
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~ after trying to print get_user_data object ~~~~~~~~~~~`")
    print(sf_auth.get_user_data())
    print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after trying to print get_user_data object as function !!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

```
within index.py
def welcome_message(datafield='fullName'):
    print('we are in the welcome message function')
    if sf_auth is None:
        return 'App is not configured with sf_auth'
    print('sf-auth')
    print(sf_auth)
    user_data = sf_auth.get_user_data()
    print('user_data')
    print(user_data)
    attribute = user_data[datafield]
    return 'Hello there {0}!'.format(attribute)
```

ANd the errors from the output

```
2023-02-28T15:17:52.316Z: stdout F SF is SOMETHING
2023-02-28T15:17:52.316Z: stdout F SF is SOMETHING
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F !!!!! after auth !!!!!!
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F <dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth object at 0x7f8051ff8070>
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F ******** after printing sf_auth object *******
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F <bound method SalesforceAuth.get_user_data of <class 'dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth'>>
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F ~~~~~~~~~~~ after trying to print get_user_data object ~~~~~~~~~~~`
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F !!!!! after auth !!!!!!
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F <dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth object at 0x7f8051e16340>
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F ******** after printing sf_auth object *******
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F <bound method SalesforceAuth.get_user_data of <class 'dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth'>>
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F ~~~~~~~~~~~ after trying to print get_user_data object ~~~~~~~~~~~`Working outside of request context.
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F information about how to avoid this problem.
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F Working outside of request context.
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
2023-02-28T15:17:52.317Z: stdout F information about how to avoid this problem.
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash_embedded/embedded_salesforce.py", line 167, in get_user_data
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:      if "salesforce_user" in session:
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z: stdout F None
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:      obj = instance._get_current_object()
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:      raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z: stdout F !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after trying to print get_user_data object as function !!!!!!!!!!!!
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash_embedded/embedded_salesforce.py", line 167, in get_user_data
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z: stdout F None
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z: stdout F !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after trying to print get_user_data object as function !!!!!!!!!!!!
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:      if "salesforce_user" in session:
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:      obj = instance._get_current_object()
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
2023-02-28T15:17:52.318Z:      raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
2023-02-28T15:17:52.322Z: stdout F SF is SOMETHINGSF is SOMETHING
2023-02-28T15:17:52.322Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F !!!!! after auth !!!!!!!!!!! after auth !!!!!!
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F <dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth object at 0x7f805292f7f0><dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth object at 0x7f8052a53df0>
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F ******** after printing sf_auth object *************** after printing sf_auth object *******
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F <bound method SalesforceAuth.get_user_data of <class 'dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth'>><bound method SalesforceAuth.get_user_data of <class 'dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth'>>
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F ~~~~~~~~~~~ after trying to print get_user_data object ~~~~~~~~~~~`~~~~~~~~~~~ after trying to print get_user_data object ~~~~~~~~~~~`
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F Working outside of request context.
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F information about how to avoid this problem.Working outside of request context.
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F information about how to avoid this problem.
2023-02-28T15:17:52.323Z: stdout F
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash_embedded/embedded_salesforce.py", line 167, in get_user_data
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:      if "salesforce_user" in session:
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z: stdout F None
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:      obj = instance._get_current_object()
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:      raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash_embedded/embedded_salesforce.py", line 167, in get_user_data
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:      if "salesforce_user" in session:
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:      obj = instance._get_current_object()
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:    File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z: stdout F !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after trying to print get_user_data object as function !!!!!!!!!!!!
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z: stdout F None
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z: stdout F !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after trying to print get_user_data object as function !!!!!!!!!!!!
2023-02-28T15:17:52.324Z:      raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F Exception on / [GET]
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in full_dispatch_request
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F     rv = self.preprocess_request()
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2312, in preprocess_request
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F     rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash_embedded/embedded_salesforce.py", line 89, in before_request
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F     raise Exception(
2023-02-28T15:17:57.598Z: stdout F Exception: Expected request method to be 'POST', found 'GET' instead
2023-02-28T15:20:01.340Z: stdout F we are in the welcome message function
2023-02-28T15:20:01.340Z: stdout F sf-auth
2023-02-28T15:20:01.340Z: stdout F <dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth object at 0x7f8051ff8070>
2023-02-28T15:20:01.340Z: stdout F user_data
2023-02-28T15:20:01.340Z: stdout F None
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F Exception on /sf-auth-2/_dash-update-component [POST]
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1259, in dispatch
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     ctx.run(
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/_callback.py", line 439, in add_context
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     output_value = func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/workspace/index.py", line 39, in display_content
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     return [welcome_message(), pages.home.layout]
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F   File "/workspace/index.py", line 55, in welcome_message
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F     attribute = user_data[datafield]
2023-02-28T15:20:01.341Z: stdout F TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
2023-02-28T17:49:07.404Z: stdout F we are in the welcome message function
2023-02-28T17:49:07.404Z: stdout F sf-auth
2023-02-28T17:49:07.404Z: stdout F <dash_embedded.embedded_salesforce.SalesforceAuth object at 0x7f805292f7f0>
2023-02-28T17:49:07.404Z: stdout F user_data
2023-02-28T17:49:07.404Z: stdout F None
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F Exception on /sf-auth-2/_dash-update-component [POST]
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1259, in dispatch
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     ctx.run(
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/_callback.py", line 439, in add_context
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     output_value = func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/workspace/index.py", line 39, in display_content
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     return [welcome_message(), pages.home.layout]
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F   File "/workspace/index.py", line 55, in welcome_message
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F     attribute = user_data[datafield]
2023-02-28T17:49:07.405Z: stdout F TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am stuck. Can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Your Form is using Method ="GET" , it needs to be Method = "POST"

Comment: POST is used by a local form to post data from the form.
GET is used to get data from a URL/Web source

Comment: This is an app running on flask which has been abstracted away by dash, so this would seem to be an issue w/ the dash package then? Is this Get/Post issue also related to the "Working outside of request context" error?

Comment: Ahh I see .. it seems perhaps so , if it is expecting one method and getting another, something is askew, and since it mentions "request context" that sounds about right.

Comment: thanks for your input! It's helpful, I'll keep digging.

Comment: Godspeed keep us posted.